# Read excel file which have 26 hundred thousand records in php or laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to read excel file.

For small file with 20 to 50 records, it work properly.

However, if I try it with large file (7 sheets, 20k records), its take too long and no response even after 2/3 hours wait time.

I have tried in maatwebsite, and spout library for reading.

Below is the spout reading code.

```
$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX); 
$reader->open($inputFileName); 
foreach($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) { 
    foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) { 
        $id= $row[0]; 
        $ntn= $row[1]; 
        $name= $row[2]; 
        $business_name= $row[3]; 
        echo $id; 
    } 
} 
$reader->close();
```

Comment: is it slow even with spout?

Comment: Please add the reading code that we can try to help optimize

Comment: yes its take too long, no any response after 2 to 3 hours I wait for the output, but its loading only @JayWadhwa and thanks for answer

Comment: here is spout reading code

Comment: $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX); 
$reader->open($inputFileName);
foreach($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $id= $row[0];
        $ntn= $row[1];
        $name= $row[2];
        $business_name= $row[3];
        echo $id;      
    }
}
$reader->close();
$conn->close();

Comment: @JayWadhwa please help me

Comment: should be taking 2-minute XLSX read
https://github.com/triad-ltd/spout/tree/develop_3.0#frequently-asked-questions

check your memory limit for PHP and then check next link
https://opensource.box.com/spout/guides/symfony-stream-content-large-spreadsheet/

Comment: @MahmoudGad Thanks going to try this